# Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.0.5.0,culture=neutral...' or one of its dependencies. Only occurs in Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, npgsql, taskscheduler

My objective of my project is to take data from Microsoft CRM and upload it to a PostGresSQL DB.  When I run the executable manually, everything works perfectly but when I run the application as a scheduled task on the Task Scheduler, I am given this error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified".

I have tried adding the following to my .csproj file but still had no luck

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>  
 <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Everything works fine up until it hits the function below.  It will not go into the function since "Print Test" is never written in the console.

```
    public void upToPostgresDB(string queryString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Print Test");
    #if DEBUG
    //Credentials below are not actually blank, I just removed them for privacy

                String pgDatabase = "";
                String pgServer = "";
                String pgUser = "";
                String pgPass = "";
    #else
                String pgDatabase = "";
                String pgServer = "";
                String pgUser = "";
                String pgPass = "";
    #endif

                String pgConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0}; UserId={1}; Password={2}; Database={3}", pgServer, pgUser, pgPass,     pgDatabase);
            NpgsqlConnection pgCon = new NpgsqlConnection(pgConnectionString);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(queryString, pgCon);            
            try
            {

                pgCon.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                pgCon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errorMessage = "Failed to upload data to the postgres database.  " + e.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                pgCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is usually emerging if your .NET Framework library uses as its dependency module also some unmanaged code library. Try to scan your library for dependencies by these applications:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/
(for "legacy" technologies and languages as C++, OCX, OLE, etc.; I am not sure if it works with MS.NET nowadays)

https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/
(for MS.NET modules scan and code decompile)

That should guide you to solution. If it will not work for you so as next step ensure you have properly configured application startup path and target paths to searching for assemblies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location

The final thing is to copy missing unmanaged code assembly to directory with your managed wrapper assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I ONLY copied and pasted the executable to the destination folder.  I needed to copy the entire Debug or Release folder as non .NET related assemblies tend to have this affect.  By having all the dependent libraries in the same folder as my .exe, this solved the issue.